Solution for Joining BigQuery tables (streaming)
I have 3 tables in BigQuery which have data constantly being appended. I want to create another table in BigQuery that is a join of these 3 tables, and I want the new table to be always updated. What's a good solution to this?

Hi @dbkoop, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

For your requirement, you can consider using Scheduled Queries by incrementally updating the data to the new table. You need to create a Scheduled Query and configure it to append the data of the 3 tables to the new table and further set the interval of time to auto update the query.
You can also try creating Materialized View for better query performance. Create a Materialized view that automatically refreshes the data of the 3 tables to the new table within the certain interval of time provided.
